# Combining multiple regressions in mlr

Tags: r, regression, multilabel-classification, mlr

Is there a way to combine multiple regressions in the `mlr` package analogously to the [multilabel classification](https://mlr.mlr-org.com/articles/tutorial/multilabel.html) with the `makeMultilabelBinaryRelevanceWrapper()`?

I have several dependent variables and and one set of features to explain them.

A Multi-Regression-Wrapper would be very convenient for calculating the overall performance and for resampling/tuning.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what do you mean by "combine"? Do you mean you want to have te predicted variables in the same data frame?

Comment: as a first step, yes. From this data frame overall performance could be calculated.

Comment: but in general, I mean more. it is also about indexing the data such that the same subsets of data are used in cross-validation for each regression for example. or for example, if I set a threshold for feature filtering then this threshold should be used for each regression to select the features which will be included into the model. The wrappers in `mlr` make a lot of this stuff much easier, usually, but not in this case not yet.

Answer (score 1):

It is not available currently. I think this and a multitarget option should be available in future. Maybe in mlr3 this will be possible.

Comment: This could be a comment.

Comment: I think I answered the question.

Comment: I would love to see this in future. Let's see if I can come up with a nice solution until then.